# Mongo DB : Impact of object schema changes on document design

Tags: mongodb

How do you handle schema changes in Mongo db e.g. say after refactoring you change your object schema design and that impacts the document schema. Is there a way to update the document schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run an update on the entire schema, removing fields, or adding fields and setting them to calculated values, if that's what you're getting at.

Say you had an x field, and you want to add a y field that should be set to x/2, you could do something like this:

```
PRIMARY> db.test.insert({x:15});
PRIMARY> db.test.insert({x:30});
PRIMARY> db.test.insert({x:50}); 
PRIMARY> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1ebed2b924eedb8cad9"), "x" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1eeed2b924eedb8cada"), "x" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1f1ed2b924eedb8cadb"), "x" : 50 }
PRIMARY> db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
            doc.y = doc.x/2; 
            db.test.save(doc); 
         });
PRIMARY> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1ebed2b924eedb8cad9"), "x" : 15, "y" : 7.5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1eeed2b924eedb8cada"), "x" : 30, "y" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9df1f1ed2b924eedb8cadb"), "x" : 50, "y" : 25 }
```

Comment: Sometimes this is easier than making your app code check for missing values (that's what I was trying to get at).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is like migrating all of your data to new schema. We have two weekly release and we support many financial products. Schema changes often for these products because of new feature. I think it would be a problem if you have more than million records to modify every release. Have you faced any such issues?

Comment: Do you care about the data in those fields for the old records? If so, you probably want to do this. If you don't care about the data in those fields, you can make your code check for its existence (and ignore the records that lack those values, or apply a calculated value, or default value lazily as you bring the data to the app). Do you have a specific example?

Comment: And yes, I have faced this issue. I usually take the easy way out and just update the data. A million records to update only takes a few minutes (unless you overrun your padding factor). It would become a problem if there were a billion records, though--I might take the longer route, in that case.

Comment: Example would be say class A has some properties and later you decide to extract these properties out and make a separate class. I would like to get the document deserialized into the domain object. This looks like a scenario which does not happen often but there are many use cases that results in restructuring of the schema. We are currently using Oracle binary xml feature and index data in elastic search. Reindexing data in elastic search takes ~hours of time. Justt wondering if this will be the same case with mongodb. Just wanted to check if you have any suggestions?